# Open and save file using devexpress htmlEditor

Tags: devexpress-mvc

I begin using the DevExpress HtmlEditor for MVC Extensions, but there is absolutely nothing on how to open and save a file. I searched about and found that it is necessary to first add a custom button to the toolbar then write the respective code. Since I couldn't find any good example for MVC I would like to know if anyone has an example on how to do these tasks, starting with adding the custom button. Trust me I searched....

Here is the code for the partial view

```
@Html.DevExpress().HtmlEditor(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "HtmlEditor1";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "HtmlEditor", Action = "HtmlEditorPartial" };
    settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.ToolbarMode = HtmlEditorToolbarMode.Menu;
    settings.SettingsDialogs.InsertImageDialog.SettingsImageUpload.UploadCallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "HtmlEditor", Action = "HtmlEditorPartialImageUpload" };
    settings.SettingsDialogs.InsertImageDialog.SettingsImageUpload.UploadFolder = HtmlEditorControllerHtmlEditor1Settings.ImageUploadDirectory;
    settings.SettingsDialogs.InsertImageDialog.SettingsImageUpload.ValidationSettings.Assign(HtmlEditorControllerHtmlEditor1Settings.ImageUploadValidationSettings);

    settings.SettingsDialogs.InsertImageDialog.SettingsImageSelector.Assign(HtmlEditorControllerHtmlEditor1Settings.ImageSelectorSettings);
}).GetHtml()
```

Comment: Do you mean a file on the clients computer?

Comment: @user5151179 Please, see my updated question

Comment: https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxHTMLEditorDemos/ToolbarItems/CustomToolbarItems